# Error with OAuth2Strategy that requires a CLIENTID

Tags: node.js, facebook, passport.js, google-authentication, clientid

I have some error when I start my app :

```
/api # yarn start
yarn run v1.21.1
$ nodemon server-express.js
[nodemon] 1.19.4
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching dir(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node server-express.js`
/api/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:86
  if (!options.clientID) { throw new TypeError('OAuth2Strategy requires a clientID option'); }
                           ^

TypeError: OAuth2Strategy requires a clientID option
    at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy (/api/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:86:34)
    at new Strategy (/api/node_modules/passport-google-oauth20/lib/strategy.js:52:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/api/helpers/authHelper.js:26:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1139:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1159:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:988:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1028:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/api/server-express.js:13:23)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1139:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1159:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:988:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

This is my .env file:

```
# NODE TODO
NODE_ENV=production
PORT=3001
HOST=localhost
# MONGO TODO
MONGO_USER=...
MONGO_DB=....
MONGO_PASS=....
MONGO_HOST=localhost
#GOOGLE_AUTH TODO
GOOGLE_CLIENTID = "....-......apps.googleusercontent.com"
GOOGLE_CLIENTSECRET = ".....-....."
GOOGLE_REDIRECT = "http://localhost:3001/auth/google/callback"
#FACEBOOK_AUTH TODO
FACEBOOK_CLIENTID = ....
FACEBOOK_CLIENTSECRET = "....."
FACEBOOK_CALLBACKURL = "http://localhost:3001/auth/facebook/callback"
FACEBOOK_TEST_EMAIL = "s....@gmail.com"
#LOCAL_URL TODO
CLIENT = "localhost:3000"
CLIENTURL = "http://localhost:3000"
SCHEMES = "http://"
SERVERAPI = "http://localhost:3001"
#GMAIL
SECRETKEY = ".....="
GMAILPSW = "....!"
SUPPORTEMAIL = "...@gmail.com"
#JWT
JWTSECRET = "...."
#COOKIE
COOKIEKEY = "...."
```

How can I resolve that?

Answer (score 0):

you need to go to

https://console.developers.google.com/

here you need to set up your application. Enable google api then search for  Google+ and then press enable api. Then create api credentials.
 once you are done you will get clientId and SecretId.

when you set up your passport.js file you have to pass those credentials to the google strategy. for safety put those credentials into a different file in your app and import them.

```
module.exports = {
  googleClientID:
    "mygooogleclientIdHERE.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  googleClientSecret: "secretIdHERE"


};
```

in passport.js

```
const keys = require("../config/keys.js");
const passport = require("passport");


passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: keys.googleClientID,
      clientSecret: keys.googleClientSecret,
      callbackURL: "/auth/google/callback"
    },
    (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
      //this is where you implement the communication between server and database

    }
  )
);
```